# Change the math in a variable using a button in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am currently working on a weather grabbing app, and I wanted to add a php function that converts the fairenheit to celcius should the user click a button. I am using the if (isset($_GET['btn-name']) format, but the string is not editing. I even do not get the error message I set up in the else part of the statement. The relevant code is where function convert() starts.

The code is below!

```
<?php
$weather = "";
$error = "";
if ($_GET['city']) {
    $urlContents = 
        file_get_contents("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
            q=".$_GET['city']."&appid=3e41ac038f5ee3839172760f9f031250");
    $weatherArray = json_decode($urlContents, true);
    $weather = "The weather in ".$_GET['city']." is currently 
            '".$weatherArray['weather'][0]['description']."'. ";
    $tempInCelcius = intval($weatherArray['main']['temp'] *9/5 - 459.67);
    $weather .= " The temperature is ".$tempInCelcius."&deg;F";
}
function convert() {
    if (isset($_GET['Convert'])) {
        $tempInCelcius = intval($weatherArray['main']['temp'] - 273);
    } else {
        echo "something went wrong";
    }
    convert();
}
?>
```

Comment: You never `echo $tempInCelcius`

Comment: The call to `convert()` needs to be outside the function. When you indent the code the problem becomes obvious.

Comment: You never do `echo $weather;` either

Comment: You need to pass `$weatherArray` as an argument to the function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response!  I actually caught that and edited it. Got my success message that the button was pressed, but the $tempInCelcius variable still does not change when the function is called. Any ideas ? Should I do this differently?

Comment: You need to learn about variable scopes. Assigning the variable inside the function has no effect on the variable outside the function. You need to return the value from the function and then assign it: `$tempInCelcius = convert($weatherArray);`

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Should I then assign it outside the function and keep what I have in the function?

Comment: Yes, that's generally good design.